# Changing the name of a service worker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to figure out what happens if I have a service worker registered on a live site called `sw.js` and then I rename the service worker to `service-worker.js`. Now the old one isn't found but it is still showing the old cached version.

How long does it take for it to register the new renamed service worker or how does this work at all?

**Edit**

This is how I have register the service worker in a react application:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("/service-worker.js")
      .then(registration => {
        console.log("service worker registration successful: ", registration);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn("service worker registration failed", err.message);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you clear out your browser's cache?

Comment: @Mathias this would work for me but I want it to update for everyone

Comment: OK, you aren't going to be changing this often, right? I'll guess most people do not.

Comment: Not really, I'm just curious on how to change this on a live site just in case.

Comment: I do realise this question isn't new, but I also see it hasn't been marked as "answered" yet... there is a _really_ good reference on MDN Web Docs that should help here, have a look specifically the "Worker lifecycle" infographic in the "Basic architecture" section over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers    otherwise, I can paraphrase the critical parts in a new answer for you a bit later if need be? TL;DR: you have _many_ ways of forcing an update, including from _within_ your new service worker logic.

Answer (score 7):

The newly created service worker (renamed) cannot take over the old one because the old one is still active and controlling the client. 
the new service worker(renamed one) will wait until the existing worker is controlling zero clients.

Now imagine a service worker `sw.js` installed and active (controlling the client),
Chrome will visualize the process for you like this

**1. The service worker is registered and active**

[image]

---

**2. Now let's rename the service worker file to `sw2.js`**

[image]

You can see that chrome is telling you that something has changed about the service worker. but the current one will keep controlling the client until you force the new one to take control by clicking on the `skipWaitting` button or by flushing your cache. clicking on the button will cause the `sw2.js`  to take controll over the `sw1.js`

Now if you need to do this programmatically, you can do it in the `install` event inside your service worker by calling `self.skipWaiting()`.

```
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {

  let cache = caches.open(cacheName).then((c) => {
    c.addAll([
      // my files
    ]);
  });

  self.skipWaiting();
  e.waitUntil(cache);
});
```

The following [animated image](https://google-developers.appspot.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle_879994428c983a10adf2a150eaca0d34.frame?hl=en) from Jake Archibald's article [The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle) can make the idea more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the instance creation code to reflect this change where your shared worker is being initialized and used, for example your current code would look like

```
var worker = new SharedWorker("ws.js");
```

That will need to be updated to

```
var worker = new SharedWorker("service-worker.js");
```

Comment: How would you do this in a reactjs application? I have added the code that I use to register the SW but I've never used the `SharedWorker` you mention.

Comment: Somewhere in your code that you deploy is "ws.js". That would need to be changed to the new name.

Comment: This is a question about ServiceWorkers and not WebWorkers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by setting up a server which listens to both `/service-worker.js` and `/sw.js` get requests.

Since the service worker was renamed from `sw.js` to `service-worker.js` it was not finding the old service worker at `http://example.com/sw.js` so what I did was the following:

```
createServer((req, res) => {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
  const { pathname } = parsedUrl;
  // new service worker
  if (pathname === "/service-worker.js") {
    const filePath = join(__dirname, "..", pathname);
    app.serveStatic(req, res, filePath);
  // added new endpoint to fetch the new service worker but with the 
  // old path
  } else if (pathname === "/sw.js") {
    const filePath = join(__dirname, "..", "/service-worker.js");
    app.serveStatic(req, res, filePath);
  } else {
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
  }
}).listen(port, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

As you can see, I added a second path to serve the same service worker but with the `/sw.js` endpoint, one for the old `sw.js` and the other one for the newer `service-worker.js`.

Now when old visitors that have the old active `sw.js` will download the newer one and upon revisit, they will automatically fetch the newer renamed `service-worker.js` service worker.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? When the old visitors comes by, the old service worker will try to fetch again the old service worker (`sw.js`) and will see the changes from the new service worker which is going to be recached now upon refreshing it will fetch from the new endpoint the new service worker.